# Ubuntu 18.04 boot loop after upgrade from 17.10

Tags: dual-boot, 17.10, 18.04

I'm running this as a dual boot on my Dell Inspiron 15 7557. I'm having a challenge after upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04. The package download  and installation process was successful (through update center). The laptop was required to reboot, to complete the upgrade, but it never made to the login screen after displaying the Ubuntu boot splash screen.
It kept displaying:

```
[ok] started gnome display manager at...link was shut down
```

Please help me.

Comment: I know this probably isn't what you want to hear, but I think you should consider doing a new install of 18.04. You can do this and still keep your old files and packages/software. Changing to a newer release with do-release-upgrade is notoriously problematic. It may seem like a pain, but if you just do a little bit of planning and preparation, a new install may even save you time in the end (since you will avoid problems with package versions/dependencies and their versions).

Comment: Thanks Emily, how would I go about this, and still keep my old files, as I am unable to login, since the boot proceed doesn't run completely.

Comment: @Andre I think you are not the only person experiencing this. So, anyone else who is also reading this. You can save your files by booting via USB, mounting the drive and then saving your files to an external storage.